# Reading and redirecting zip file by Less

Tags: bash, ssh

Im trying to copy a zip file located on a server by a  ssh2 library.
the way i'm about to do is using less command and write it down on client side.

```
Less -r -L -f zipfile
```

but the output file is bigger than the original.
i know this not a good practice but i have to.
so how can i handle this to have my zip file on the client machine?

Answer (score 0):

Is `Less` an mandatory command to do that ?

You can simply use `scp` to achieve that by providing user and host and then typing the directory, where to copy the file from the server to local host, like on the example below:

```
scp your_username@remotehost.edu:foobar.txt /some/local/directory
```

Comment: absolutely not! but in my case i should  do it by less. tnx4answer